# Sealed classes and Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2008, class, sealed

While inspecting the the .net object model in the Object Browser window, I came across the lack of information on sealed classes.

If for instance, one navigates to the mscorlib container **->** System namespace **->** String class, the details pane displays the following:

> public class **String**
>        Member of **System**
>
> **Summary:**
>   Represents text as a series of Unicode characters.
>
> **Attributes:**
>   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true),
>   System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute("Chars")]

It seems I can only ascertain if a class is sealed either through the Code Definition Window or, of course, by trying to derive from it.

Yet, while following `Apress - Pro C# 2008 and the .Net 3.5 Platform`, by Andrew Troelsen, the author shows on page 188 how the object browser display the sealed status:

[image]

**Has this information been removed from Visual Studio 2008 object browser? Could I get it back somehow?**

Although the author mentions Visual Studio 2008 throughout the text, that screenshot must be from a previous version. The book is in fact in its 4th Edition, and started back in 2001 with .Net 1.0 Beta 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a couple of years, but I'd just like to confirm I can see this in VS2k8 SP1, but *only* for `String`.

I think it is because `String` is the only `class` that has been marked as "special" (primitive type perhaps?) along with `Integer`, `Long`, etc, which are all `ValueTypes` (`structures`).

Note in the image in the question `SByte`, `Single` and `String` do *not* have the same icon in the LHS treeview where as they do now.

**Edit:** It's been another couple of years and I've just noticed for VB.NET in VS2k8 SP1 it *does* say `Public NotInheritable Class String` when I have the Object Browser Browse selection set to My Project or All Components*, but only `Public Class String` when I select a specific .NET Framework (and yet Attributes are listed, whereas they're not in the other Browse selections).

*As in the display captured in the OP!

NB It only updates the display if you shift off `String` and back on it again on the LHS treeview. And VS2010 SP1 behaves identically.

<sub>In VS2010 I see All Components showing `String` as both `NotInheritable`, for .NET 4, and "blank" for .NET 2 and Silverlight, but I can't currently confirm what VS2008 shows in a similar situation.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

My Visual Studio 2008 does not seem to have this issue. Are you upgraded to SP1? Do you have other tools or add-ins that modify the Object Browser's functionality?

Comment: I'm running VS Team System 2008 - Team Suit from my MSDN subscription. It is upgraded to SP1. Could someone confirm a similar behavior under this SKU?