# 'Decimal' source code from Microsoft - will it build?

Tags: c#, .net

I was recently attempting to answer [a question that a user posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501369/decimal-minvalue-decimal-maxvalue-why-static-readonly-and-not-const-modifiers/21502108?noredirect=1#comment32460610_21502108) about why the `decimal` struct does not declare its Min/Max values as `const` like every other numeric primitive; rather, the Microsoft documentation states that it is `static readonly.`

In researching that, I dug through the Microsoft source code, and came up with an interesting discovery; the source (.NET 4.5) makes it look like a `const` which is in opposition to what the documentation clearly states (source and relevant struct constructor pasted below).

```
public const Decimal MinValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, true, (byte) 0);
public const Decimal MaxValue = new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, false, (byte) 0);

public Decimal(int lo, int mid, int hi, bool isNegative, byte scale)
{
  if ((int) scale > 28)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("scale", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_DecimalScale"));
  this.lo = lo;
  this.mid = mid;
  this.hi = hi;
  this.flags = (int) scale << 16;
  if (!isNegative)
    return;
  this.flags |= int.MinValue;
}
```

The thread here continues to unravel, because I can't see how this would compile legally under the rules of C# - because while it still is *technically* a constant, the compiler thinks it isn't and will give you an error `The expression being assigned to ... must be constant`.  Hence what I believe is the reason that the docs call it a `static readonly`.

**Now, this begs a question: is this file from the Microsoft source server *actually* the source for decimal, or has it been doctored? Am I missing something?**

Comment: I'm not certain of the details but know that the core .Net libraries are compiled in a non-standard way. One example of this is that circular references are allowed across assemblies (assembly 1 references a type in assembly 2 which in turn references a type in assembly 1). This would lead me to believe the compiler used for the core libraries isn't the stock one released to the public. That said, I can't find the article discussing the topic

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few aspects of mscorlib and the like which wouldn't compile as-written, without some interesting hacks. In particular, there are some cyclic dependencies. This is another case, but I think it's reasonable to consider `MaxValue` and `MinValue` as being `const` as far as the C# compiler is concerned.

In particular, it's valid to use them within other `const` calculations:

```
const decimal Sum = decimal.MaxValue + decimal.MinValue;
```

The fields have the [`DecimalConstantAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.decimalconstantattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) applied to them, which is effectively a hack to get around an impedance mismatch between C# and the CLR: you can't have a constant field of type `decimal` in the CLR in the same way that you can have a constant field of type `int` or `string`, with an IL declaration using `static literal ...`.

(This is also why you can't use `decimal` values in attribute constructors - there, the "const-ness" requirement is true IL-level constness.)

Instead, any `const decimal` declaration in C# code is compiled to a `static initonly` field with `DecimalConstantAttribute` applied to it specifying the appropriate data. The C# compiler uses that information to treat such a field as a constant expression elsewhere.

Basically, `decimal` in the CLR isn't a "known primitive" type in the way that `int`, `float` etc are. There are no `decimal`-specific IL instructions.

Now, in terms of the specific C# code you're referring to, I suspect there are two possibilities:

- No, this isn't the exact source code used.
- The C# compiler used to compile mscorlib and other core aspects of the framework may have special flags applied to allow such code, converting it directly to `DecimalConstantAttribute`

To a large extent you can ignore this - it won't affect you. It's a shame that MSDN documents the fields as being `static readonly` rather than `const` though, as that gives the mistaken impression that one can't use them in `const` expressions :(

Comment: This certainly seems to be along the lines of what I was thinking, but you clearly know a lot more about the "guts" of .NET. I've heard that decimal is less primitive, but what makes it so? Is it due to implementation?

Comment: @rmayer06: It's not a primitive in terms of the CLR - for example, `typeof(decimal).IsPrimitive` returns false. The CLR doesn't have any special knowledge of `decimal` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: "It's a shame that MSDN documents the fields as being `static readonly` ": Well much of the documentation is based upon the actual declarations as can be seen by Reflector or other decompilers. Just like `String` [not being seen as `sealed` sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6936430/256431) in the Object Browser, I think this is just another [quirk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530321/256431).