# How to test with decimal.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, decimal

Consider the following test:

```
public void FooTest(decimal? val)
{
    Check.That(true).IsTrue();
}
```

I want to run this test with *extreme* values (i.e. `MaxValue` and `MinValue`).

```
[TestCase(decimal.MaxValue)]
```

This outputs the following error : An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

```
[TestCase(79228162514264337593543935)]
```

I get this one now : Integral constant is too large

One last desperate try:

```
[TestCase(79228162514264337593543935M)]
```

Obviously I get this one because of the cast : An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

How does one write a unit test with `decimal.MaxValue` as a parameter? I could write a specific test for this problematic case but I would like to know if there's a way to write a `TestCase` like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Decimal.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a constant, it is a `static` `readonly` field. Which means you can't use it in attributes as attributes require constants. You'll have to hard code it.

[Visual studio will pretend it as a `const` but it is actually not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502561/decimal-source-code-from-ms-source-will-it-build).

```
bool isConstant = typeof (decimal)
    .GetField("MaxValue", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .IsLiteral;
//isConstant will be false :(
```

Comment: In short visual studio cheats us :p

Comment: Why is it const here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs ??

Comment: @T_D Well, Jon has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502561/decimal-source-code-from-ms-source-will-it-build)

Comment: This might be correct (although reference source disagrees) but even `[TestCase(1m)]` fails. Decimals simply can't be used in this context. The compiled IL code treats decimals differently to ints.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Very nice answer also to the specific question of OP

Comment: Misleading. In C# terms, certainly `decimal.MaxValue` is a `const`. Otherwise, how would the following C# be allowed: `const decimal SriramsNumber = decimal.MaxValue; /* OK */`? The type `System.Decimal` cannot appear as argument in any attribute application, though, but that is something else. If you look at the generated IL, you will see that there is an attribute `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DecimalConstantAttribute`. That is how a constant of type `decimal` looks in CLR. However, constants of _primitive_ types (CLR) are `static literal` in the IL, but `decimal` constants cannot be.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Who cares about c# terms when question is about `decimal.MaxValue` and `Attribute` neither of them is c# property. Both are properties of .Net framework, for the clr my answer is right. c# compiler does the magic by automatically converting the `const` field to `readonly` may be other compilers don't do that. Also questioner didn't asked in c#'s perspective. Nevermind about the downvote, your comment is likely to help future readers. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: It is correct that `System.Decimal::MaxValue` from a CLR point of view is not `literal` (you used the C# term `const`), instead it is `initonly` (you used the C# keyword `readonly`). But surely the struct `System.Decimal` is written in C#, and in that language the "constant" (C# terminology) `MaxValue` must necessarily be written as `public const decimal MaxValue ...`. If it had been `public static readonly decimal MaxValue ...` in C#, this member would have entirely different semantics in C#.

Comment: The reason why I found you answer a bit misleading, is that it comes close to saying that this particular member `MaxValue` is not constant/literal enough. But it is as constant as any `System.Decimal` can be. Your answer is almost like saying "The reason why `[TestCase(79228162514264337593543935M)]` (or `[TestCase(0M)]`) does not work is that `79228162514264337593543935M` is not a constant!" In some sense it is technically correct, but not the most optimal explanation. However, it is helpful, after all, to understand why a `const decimal` is not `.IsLiteral`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I see you're pedantic. I used c# term readonly because many of the people may not be knowing term `InitOnly` and same thing for `IsLiteral` also. I believe you can give a deep insight in new answer, If you provide a accurate explanation if your answer you own my upvote..

Comment: Downvoted, it does not answer the question, it only explains why. Oliver posted a working solution.

Comment: @MeanGreen [You may need to read this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Answer (score 20):

Now that all others have said, why this problem occurs, your code should use the [`TestCaseSource`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute to write your test:

```
private static object[] TestValues = 
{
    new object[]{ Decimal.MaxValue },
    new object[]{ Decimal.MinValue }
};

[TestCaseSource("TestValues")]
public void FooTest(decimal value)
{
    Assert.That(value, Is.EqualTo(Decimal.MaxValue));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. If you find it nicer (no boxing etc. on _your_ side), you could write `private static decimal[][] testValues = { new[] { Decimal.MaxValue }, new[] { Decimal.MinValue }, };` instead, if I remember correctly (did not test it right now).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That's right, but this won't work if you have multiple arguments and the performance penalty for boxing at this point is not really measureable, why i normally stick to the object array.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter whether you try to use `[TestCase(Decimal.MaxValue)]` or use a literal like `[TestCase(1m)]`. Neither will work.

According to the C# specification (17.1.3, Attribute parameter types):

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>   •   One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
>   •   The type object.
>   •   The type System.Type.
>   •   An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (§17.2).
>   •   Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

Notice the absence of decimal in the first list item.

The error message is a bit misleading because same specification also says that a `decimal` can be a constant expression (7.19).

But if you look at the IL code when creating a `decimal` you'll see that it actually invokes a constructor call: `newobj System.Decimal..ctor`. And that's unlike other literals, e.g. `ldc.r8 33 33 33 33 33 33 F3 3F` for `var a = 1.2;`.