# C# How do value types contain fields of their own type?

Tags: c#, floating-point, primitive, integral, value-type

Im trying to understand more about how value types are implemented and represented in C#, and was confused when I saw that the Single struct/value type is defined as so:

```
public struct Single : IComparable, IComparable<Single>, IConvertible, IEquatable<Single>, IFormattable
{
    public const Single Epsilon = 1.401298E-45F;
    public const Single MaxValue = 3.40282347E+38F;
    public const Single MinValue = -3.40282347E+38F;
    public const Single NaN = 0F / 0F;
    public const Single NegativeInfinity = -1F / 0F;
    public const Single PositiveInfinity = 1F / 0F;

    // etc ...
}
```

How can the struct Single contain Singles in itself? Or in other words, how can the definition of type contain instances of that type? If I try to do this with my own struct, the compiler returns an error. Is is that the actual underlying values are C++ primitives, and the "value type" is just a collection of methods wrapped around it?
I think ultimately Im confused by the distinction between "primitive" and "value type." If they are primitives, why are they defined as structs?

Comment: `public const float Epsilon = (float)1.4e-45;` etc.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `Single` is just a wrapper. Are you sure you can't include constants of the same type in a struct in your own code? `Color.colorname` is, as far as I remember, a lot of constants too.

Comment: What I meant is the the definition of `Single` you're showing doesn't match the .Net Source code of [struct Single](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,31), which uses `float` instead.

Comment: Fields, constants and statics are not the same thing at all. It is easy to think of them like that due to the similar definition. | Statics only exist once in memory. Outside of any class instance. That Single.Epsilon is the same as a Foo.Epsilon would be. | now constants - they actualy never make it into the compiled code. All appereances of `Single.Epsilon` will be replaced with the literal `1.401298E-45F`, as much as you had written it there yourself. | fields are very speicifcally for *instance* variables. Wich neither const nor static are.

Comment: For the record, you get a compiler error that says "The type 'x' cannot be declared const", and I believe that is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Christopher, fields can be `static`

Comment: @ASh Oh irhgt, I had missed the part about the Static fields. I thought they were not fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you try this, the compiler complains that your struct cannot be made `const` ("*The type 'MyStruct' cannot be declared const*").

I asked a [similar question about `decimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502561/decimal-source-code-from-microsoft-will-it-build) once upon a time. The answer, given by Jon Skeet himself, is that there are things in the source for `mscorlib` that won't compile as-written without "some interesting hacks."

My guess is that you've come across one of these. `Single` is a synonym of `float`, which itself is a primitive type. The source is probably not a clean abstraction of the actual compiled/CLR type.

Comment: The answer was a const, so it did not mater. Constants do not actually make it into the compiled code. The values they are set to, do. That example is the same as if you had written the result of the calculation `decimal.MaxValue + decimal.MinValue` at every point they appear.

Comment: @Christopher - my answer was geared toward the specific question asked, and that's "why can't I do this in my own code?"

Answer (score 1):

Any type can use itself in it's code.

This rule has been around since the early days of Object Oriented Programming. You can see it best in C++, where there is a explicit difference between Declarations and Definitions:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/

Basically you can declare that somewhere in this code (or another file), there is a definition for a "variable X". And can then use the "variable X", as if you had put it there with a include directive or fully defined. That way you can make something similar to the partial file.

For functions the process is called "prototyping".

Classes can kinda do it, within limits. In C++ you can not have a *field* of the type itself in itself, because that would mean each Instance would contain another isntance, causing a compiler recursion. [And bloating up the type to infinite size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706136/3346583). However you can have a *pointer* of the type. And in .NET we have references. And as both pointers and references can be null, there is no issue. It *may* contain a refrence recursion at runtime. But it does not at compile time and that is good enough for the compiler.

But these processes were nessesary, due to the Idiosyncracies of the Native C++ compilation method: Each file is compiled after the other. And include directives actually **insert the code**, really bloating the file Size between Pre-Processor and Compiler.

```
//Prototype of a function
double someFunction( double, int );

//Declaration of a variable
extern int y;
```

The thing is that by the time the C# compiler was made, they had evolved past the *need* for Prototypes and declarations. It can figure out that in this file or some other file there is a definition for the type "Single", so it can use the type "Single". Inlcuding the code of Single itself. Indeed it does so, every time you use a partial class - so every time you used a Windows Forms Designer.

With statics and constants, it is not even an issue:

- Statics are stored outside of the class instances. They are somewhere in memory, but the compiler takes care of that. And most importantly, they are only there once. No danger of recursion.
- While compile time constants, will just have the value written in the resulting MSIL. So again, not stored in the class.

Comment: But, he need to know also about  **C# How do value types contain fields of their own type?** and me too ;)   I know some classes like Color.Empty; which return Color

Comment: @deveton The same way a function can be used before it's definition in C++. Minus the need for a prototype like construct. The compiler finds a way.